# How to get page up/down arrows to show in document viewer?

Tags: user-interface

When I open a pdf file in document viewer there are no page up/down arrows. I have to scroll through the document using the sidebar or up/down keys. I like using the page up/down buttons to quickly get to the page I need or browse through pages. How do I get them back in document viewer?

The up/down arrows are in Linux Mint and Xubuntu. They are usually to the left of the page number box.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, they removed those arrows from the UI in one of the latest updates. You can use keyboard shortcuts, though: press <kbd>N</kbd> to go to the next page in the document, and <kbd>P</kbd> to go to the previous page.